# Launch Neo4j 2.3.2 from the commandline

Tags: terminal, neo4j

I have installed Neo4j 2.3.2 Community Edition on Mac OS 10.10. I can launch the application and connect to it from localhost:7474/browser/. So far, so good.

I would like to launch Neo4j 2.3.2 from a Terminal window, so that I don't have the overhead of a windowed application running at the same time. When I run the following command...

```
$ ~/neo4j/bin/neo4j console
```

... I get this output in the Terminal window:

```
WARNING: Max 256 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Starting Neo4j Server console-mode...
Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".
Using additional JVM arguments:  -server -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dorg.neo4j.server.properties=conf/neo4j-server.properties -Djava.util.logging.config.file=conf/logging.properties -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:hashCode=5 -Dneo4j.ext.udc.source=tarball
2016-02-25 14:03:18.755+0000 INFO  [API] Setting startup timeout to: 120000ms based on 120000
2016-02-25 14:03:58.356+0000 INFO  [API] Successfully started database
2016-02-25 14:04:04.220+0000 INFO  [API] Starting HTTP on port :7474 with 2 threads available
2016-02-25 14:04:13.512+0000 INFO  [API] Enabling HTTPS on port :7473
09:04:20.201 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @98517ms
2016-02-25 14:04:23.034+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/webadmin] from [webadmin-html]
2016-02-25 14:04:25.785+0000 INFO  [API] Mounting static content at [/browser] from [browser]
09:04:25.993 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.2.4.v20141103
09:04:26.722 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.h.MovedContextHandler@1611ba2{/,null,AVAILABLE}
09:04:27.794 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /webadmin, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
09:04:27.981 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@132ea25{/webadmin,jar:file:/Users/james/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-server-2.2.5-static-web.jar!/webadmin-html,AVAILABLE}
09:04:38.841 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@60bfaa02{/db/manage,null,AVAILABLE}
09:04:39.326 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@28e2e149{/db/data,null,AVAILABLE}
09:04:39.353 [main] INFO  o.e.j.w.StandardDescriptorProcessor - NO JSP Support for /browser, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
09:04:39.355 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@78e6aa71{/browser,jar:file:/Users/james/neo4j/system/lib/neo4j-browser-2.2.5.jar!/browser,AVAILABLE}
09:04:39.536 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@4994d9ab{/,null,AVAILABLE}
09:04:39.745 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@2d19cf20{HTTP/1.1}{localhost:7474}
09:04:40.576 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.ServerConnector - Started ServerConnector@43c742c{SSL-HTTP/1.1}{localhost:7473}
09:04:40.577 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @119058ms
2016-02-25 14:04:40.577+0000 INFO  [API] Server started on: http://localhost:7474/
2016-02-25 14:04:40.590+0000 INFO  [API] Remote interface ready and available at [http://localhost:7474/]
```

I have Java version 8, update 74 installed (build 1.8.0_74-b02), so I assume that I can ignore the warning `Unable to find any JVMs matching version "1.7".`

However, when I visit http://localhost:7474/ in Chrome Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit), I see three errors in the Developer Console: two files that fail to load and a subsequent script error.

```
localhost/:28 GET http://localhost:7474/browser/styles/68eddd94.main.css 
localhost/:466 GET http://localhost:7474/browser/scripts/ded362b3.scripts.js
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module neo4jApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'neo4jApp' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

As a result, the Neo4j interface does not appear in the browser window.

Is it possible to run Neo4j 2.3.2 from the Terminal, and if so, what do I need to do to get `http://localhost:7474/` to load correctly?

Comment: `$ ~/neo4j/bin/neo4j start` doesn't work?

Comment: No, it gives the same results but without all the helpful output in the Terminal window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift-reload, or test in an incognito window.

Looks like a JS file mismatch due to aggressive browser caching.